# PHP преобразовать тег в текст

Tags: php

Как в PHP преобразовать этот текст `<a href="">asd</a>` в ссылку в html?
Пробую через echo - выводит тег как текст.

Comment: Не верю! 11 символов

Comment: всё из за content-type заголовка :D какой сервер стоит!

Comment: покажите код, которым выводите этот тег на страницу.

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо заключить текст, передаваемый в `echo`, в двойные кавычки.

```
echo "<a href='/'>link</a>";
```

И установить `Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8`.

Comment: вот про контент-тайп оставьте и распишите подробнее, а ерунду про кавычки уберите)